# Show facebook user detail in ios app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook

After the user sing in whit Facebook to my app i wont to display his first name and profile pic, I get the data from AppDelegate class and add it to a property (UserNameLable) in the view controller,

in AppDelegate all the nslogs shows the data
in the view controller nslogs shows null
how can i loud the data in to my property in the mainViewController ?

in AppDelegate this is the code

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *first_name_property;
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
             postNotificationName:SCSessionStateChangedNotification
             object:session];


                [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {

                    if (error) {

                        NSLog(@"error");
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        NSLog(@"FB user first name:%@",user.first_name);
                        NSLog(@"FB user last name:%@",user.last_name);

                        // Add the data to the property I crated 
                        first_name_property = user.first_name;


                    }
                }];



            }

            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            break;

        default:
            break;
```

//this is the code to display the data in my view

**mainViewController.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *UserNameLable;
```

**mainViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    if (!UserNameLable) {
        UserNameLable.text=((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).first_name_property;

    }
    else{
        UserNameLable.text=@"not set";}
}
```

Comment: where are you loading the mainViewController. It should be called on sessionStateChanged, after setting the first_name_property on AppDelegate.m. The mainViewController is synchronous where the facebook must be asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

Use **`first_name_property`** instead of first_name.

Try

```
UserNameLable.text=((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).first_name_property;
```